# How to checkout svn+ssh repository with subgit?

Tags: git, svn, ssh, glassfish, subgit

I want to checkout the glassfish svn with `subgit` 2.0.2.

I added

```
ssh-rsa blabla user@host
```

in the user account settings of java.net. The key is stored locally under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `id_rsa.user@host.pub`.

I set up `subgit` with `subgit configure --svn-url  svn+ssh://javauser@svn.java.net/glassfish~svn /path/to/folder` and changed `/path/to/folder/config` to

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
    logallrefupdates = false
    bigFileThreshold = 1m

[svn]
    url =  svn+ssh://javauser@svn.java.net/glassfish~svn 

[auth "default"]
    sshKeyFile = /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.user@host.pub
```

`subgit install /path/to/folder` fails due to `error: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'javauser@svn+ssh://svn.java.net'`.

**Edit 1 and 3:** I want to checkout with `svn+ssh` because with `svn` and `https` I'm getting

- `error: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/': 405 Method Not Allowed (https://svn.java.net)` or
- `error: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/glassfish~svn': 502 Proxy Error (https://svn.java.net)`

after different periods of time (sometime immediately, sometimes after days (it's a large checkout...), but I never managed to checkout/clone completely), with `http` I'm getting relocation error because the server enforces `https` this way.

**Edit 2:** When I invoke `ssh javauser@svn.java.net` and `ssh javauser@java.net` I'm getting `Permission denied (publickey).` and I'm not sure whether this is intended, because I guess I shouldn't be able to login on the java.net server or whether the key isn't working.

**EDIT 3:** java.net seems to let all `REPORT` requests (I'm not too familiar with `svn`, maybe that's very rare and relies on some extension of underlying protocoll which get stuck in a misconfigured firewall - why else could it timeout always on `REPORT` requests?) making it impossible to checkout even with `svn`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `subgit` isn't using your SSH key for the authorization.

I guess you have to specify the `auth` value for the `svn` configuration, although one could assume that it is using the `default` by default. Try the following:

```
[svn]
    url = svn+ssh://javauser@svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn 
    auth = default
```

**Update:** I just realized that you are using the wrong URL. It has to be:

> svn.java.net/**svn**/glassfish~svn

**Update #2:**

If you don't want to contribute to the repository an anonymous checkout is sufficient. Try the following configuration:

```
[svn]
    url = https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn
    auth = default

[auth "default"]
```

I tried that and it started, but it looks like it will take ages to complete. Maybe it helps if only checkout something more specific like the GlassFish 4.0 branch (change the url to https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/4.0/).

If this also doesn't work for you another option is to checkout the repository with `svn` (like it is supposed to). The following should work (you need an `svn` client for that):

```
svn checkout https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn /path/to/something
```

You can also do a local import of the `svn` checkout with `subgit`. Instructions can be found in the [SubGit Book for Local Mode](http://subgit.com/book/#installation-stages).

**See also:**

- [SubGit Remote Book - Installation Stages](http://subgit.com/book-remote/index.html#installation-stages)
- [How do I set up subgit to mirroe an svn repo that looks like a Windows Explorer hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187431/how-do-i-set-up-subgit-to-mirroe-an-svn-repo-that-looks-like-a-windows-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for you input, but that's not it. I edited the tail of the question. Maybe that inspires to some new ideas :)

Comment: about your update: The checkout URL for `https`, `http` and `svn` is `<prot>://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn`, but access via SSH is without `svn` subdirectory `svn+ssh://javauser@svn.java.net/glassfish~svn` [https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show] - anyway, both don't work!

Comment: Do you want to contribute to the repository? Otherwise an anonymous checkout could be sufficient.

Comment: No, I don't. The anonymous checkout fails due to `PROPFIND` error described in my (updated) question (marking the update now) (I assume there's no other protocol besides `http`, `https`, `svn` and `svn+ssh`)

Comment: Thanks! I tried once to checkout 4.0, but it seems to have so much redundancy with the main branch (I guess I mean trunk in svn terms) that it takes also days, but that's no problem. I guess the only issue is the `PROPFIND` issue which occurs during anonymus checkout.

Comment: Correct url is: svn+ssh://svn.java.net/glassfish~svn